# How to specify another class to hidden input wrapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I update the project from bootstrap v.3 to bootstrap v.4. I update simple_form and now, when I specify simple_form input tag as 'hidden':

```
= f.input :id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: nil }
```

It creates an input with wrapper:

```
<div class="form-group hidden integer optional"></div>
```

But in current version bootstrap hidden class have been removed.
How can I change it, for example on 'd-none' class?

Comment: `<input class="form-control hidden" type="hidden">` What about attribute `type=hidden`? it should be added as well and hide input field. I've just tested this with newest bootstrap(4.3.1) and rails 5.2.3 and element was hidden correctly

Comment: `type="hidden"` works correct and hide input field, but input wrapper is still showing. I know, that I can write `= f.input :id, as: :hidden, wrapper: false, input_html: { value: nil }`, but I have a lot of such fields, I would like to change everything at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you this this?

```rb
= f.input :id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: nil }, wrapper_html: { class: 'yourclass' }
```

Comment: I understood, simple_form take name from `as: :hidden` option and add it to class. So I can't change `hidden` class to another, but yes, I can add an additional class. Only in my case I need to add it to wrapper, so correct answer is `= f.input :id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: nil }, wrapper_html: { class: "myclass" }` or it is possible not to display wrapper for hidden inputs by add `wrapper: false`